# run a local node fail: solana-test-validator fail

Tags: local-cluster, network, wsl

I use wsl2 in windows11: ubuntu 20.04. And I set the proxy in the ~/.bashrc:

```
export https_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:7890"
export http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:7890"
```

I follow this [article](https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/getting-started/start-a-solana-local-validator) to run a local validator node. But I meet some trouble:

```
levi@LEVI-104-PC:/opt/solana/solana-local-validator$ solana-test-validator
--faucet-sol argument ignored, ledger already exists
Ledger location: test-ledger
Log: test-ledger/validator.log
⠓ Initializing...
Waiting for fees to stabilize 1...
Identity: 8tyfD7vG2shknYLoXWo9SQA3eNf8v8NMH5WvZnQTugnL
Genesis Hash: BaLEwHBR8Qhz7MW6xZnEffW5MT4XyrPDN2NVezyBC1nj
Version: 1.16.28
Shred Version: 52617
Gossip Address: 127.0.0.1:1024
TPU Address: 127.0.0.1:1027
JSON RPC URL: http://127.0.0.1:8899
WebSocket PubSub URL: ws://127.0.0.1:8900
  RPC connection failure: error sending request for url (http://127.0.0.1:8899/): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: Canno
Failed to get validator identity over RPC: error sending request for url (http://127.0.0.1:8899/): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: Cannot assign requested address (os error 99)
Failed to get validator identity over RPC: error sending request for url (http://127.0.0.1:8899/): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: Cannot assign requested address (os error 99)
Failed to get validator identity over RPC: error sending request for url (http://127.0.0.1:8899/): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: Cannot assign requested address (os error 99)
Failed to get validator identity over RPC: error sending request for url (http://127.0.0.1:8899/): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: Cannot assign requested address (os error 99)
```

I have tried these command, but does not work:

```
solana-test-validator -C --gossip-host 0.0.0.0 --gossip-port 8899
solana-test-validator -C --gossip-host 0.0.0.0
solana-test-validator -C --gossip-host 0.0.0.0 -l --rpc-port 8899
...
```

When I delete the proxy configuration in `~/.bashrc` and don't use vpn in windows, it can work. What should I do to work with the proxy configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried checking if the ports are used by other processes?

Comment: I uses lsof to check which ports are available

Comment: I have checked it, but no processes uses 8899 port.

Comment: How about binding the process to 0.0.0.0 instead of 120.0.0.1

Comment: I have tried: `--gossip-host 0.0.0.0` and `--rpc-port 8899`, but it does not work. When using `--gossip host 0.0.0.0`, there are no errors, but it doesn't run correctly. Finally exit directly.